# Conditional density of normal distribution

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, expectation, conditional-expectation, density-function

The following question comes from Sheldon Ross's Example 6b in Properties of Expectation chapter.

Suppose that if a signal value *s* is sent from location *A*, then the signal value received at location B is normally distributed with parameters (*s*, 1). If *S* is the value of the signal sent at *A*, is normally distributed with parameters *(μ, $σ^2$)*, what is the vest estimate of the signal sent if *R*, the value received at *B*, is equal to *r*?

Solution: Let us start by first computing the conditional density of *S* given *R*. We have 
$$
f_{(S|R)}(s|r) = \frac{f_{(S,R)}(s,r)}{f_R(r)}
$$

$$
= \frac{f_{(S)}(s)f_{(R|S)}(r|s)}{f_R(r)}
$$

$$
Ke^{-(s-μ)^2/2σ^2}e^{-(r-s)^2/2}
$$

where K does not depend on s.

I mostly follow what happens after this statement, but I'm confused as to how this original equation is derived, specifically $e^{-(r-s)^2/2}$. I'm not understanding where this value comes from, and where $f_R(r)$ comes into play.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

We are given that the conditional distribution of $R$ given $S=s$ is normal with mean $s$ and variance $1$. This means the conditional density of $R$ given $S=s$ is the following function of $r$:
$$
f_{(R|S)}(r|s) = \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{(r-s)^2/2}.
$$
Now substitute this into 
$$\frac{f_{(S)}(s)f_{(R|S)}(r|s)}{f_R(r)}.
$$
You can collect everything that doesn't depend on $s$ into a multiplicative constant $K$. This $K$ includes the density $f_R(r)$ -- which explains why it seems to have disappeared.